# WP7 app could not start for debugging

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, windows-phone-7, emulation, crash

I have to create around 200 WP7 apps that are very similar. They differ only in the content, icons and name. So manually create them isn't a good idea so let's I've written a little tool, which does the following:

1. Copy the created template project
2. Copy the content files from a source directory to the copied template.
3. Change the app name, tile name and app id in the WMAppManifest.xml
4. Add the copied content files in the .csproj-file.

This works and the generated project opens error-free in Visual Studio 2010 and compiles without errors. The xap-file can be deployed on device and emulator.

The problems:
If I want to debug the app by pressing F5 in Visual Studio I get "The application could not be launched for debugging. Ensure that the target device screen is unlocked and that application is installed", both for device (which is unlocked and connected with Zune/WPConnect) and the emulator.
If I try to start the app on the emulator it closes immediatle after start. BUT if I start the app on my device it works like a charm. Crazy stuff.

The curious stuff: If I do the things which my little tool does manuelly I can debug the project from Visual Studio.
This only occures with my generated projects. Every other WP7 project (existing or newly created within VS) works and debugs error-free.

I tried to PCs: Win7 x64 with VS2010 Ultimate and an other one Win7 x64/VS2010 Pro and on both maschines I have the problem.

Maybe someone has an idea which causes the problem. Thanks for the help!

Edit: I've seen something new: The AssemblyInfo.cs file is located in the properties folder and correctly included in the csproj-file. But if I try to open the Assembly Information from the project properties all fields are empty and if I try to set them I get an error ("value is not in the expected range" or something like this).

Answer (score 1):

I've got similar problem with some sample programs.
It turned out that I have to set in a Solution properties:

```
Active config => Debug|Windows Phone
```

it works for me

Answer (score 0):

If they only differ in content, icons, and name, would it be simpler to make one complete app, copy it 199 times, and then just put the appropriate files into the correct directories?(if you made a tool to make templated projects, i'm sure you could do this with code too)

Plus that way if you ever need to change the program you can just recopy with that code again, but not copy the content, thus updating all of your individual 200 apps.

Comment: This is my manually way but it takes much more time and because some content is variable (differ in number of files) it takes time to insert them all in VS. But my tool does exactly this what I do manually and it doesn't debug :/

Comment: hmm... I would check to make sure everything is getting changed in the manifest, or else check to see if there is some project property that needs to get changed for each copy

Comment: I  have used a diff tool and couldn't find any things that I missed to changed.